# Check if request is Get AND Post

Tags: php

I know I can check if requesti is POST with

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
```

or GET with

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')
```

But I need to check if request is both POST and GET.
Something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET)
```

Because I need to display both post and get parameters from the following code:

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php?a=1&b=2&c=3">
<input list="isp" name="isp" id="ispf" value="SiOL">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Its either one or the other, not both. If you submit the form, you will have a POST request with some query parameters.

Comment: You can't use both methods to handle data.

Comment: @putvande is correct. You do not have to make those checks to access the variables. Instead check if the variables exist, one by one. _That_ is what you are interested in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request cannot be Both POST and GET at the same time, i think i understand your question.

To get the querystring values on a POST request you can do:

```
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$queryStringAsDictionary = parse_str($queryString);
```

And get the Post values with $_POST

Answer (score 2):

it will helps you

```
$isp = $_REQUEST['isp'];
$a = $_REQUEST['a'];
```

you don't need to check the **method**, just read value using `$_REQUEST['variable_name']`  can read both **$_POST**
 anf **$_GET** variables
keep going

Comment: Just make sure to read the note on the [docs for $_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) :

The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET, POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP variables_order configuration directive.